# ios - How to prevent UICollectionview scrolling when new cell is added

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a messenger app, conversations are displayed in a `UICollectionview`.

When a new message is received, a new item is added to bottom of the `collectionview`. Everything is ok when user has scrolled to the bottom of the view, but when user scrolls up (to older messages) and a new message is received, `collectionview` scrolls to the bottom a bit (about new message's size).
I want to keep the `collectionview` position and prevent scrolling when a new message is received and `collectionview` updates. How should I do this?

Comment: I guess that is an intended feature when you use the provided layout flow. You have 2 alternative here: write your custom layout or save the content offset of the collection view and later restore it without animation, probably this will show a glitch.

Comment: append it to the array and then reloadData() ?

Comment: the collectionView has heavy data, reloadData() would decrease performance I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution can be to store your new messages in date model and add after user scroll to bottom. You do not need them before that because user can view them . That will fix your problems with scroll